# Use Excel Match Result as Column Selection

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, excel-match

I have a `MATCH` expression that returns the valid row number.

I now need to combine this result with a known Column identifier to return the results of that cell.

So, if something on `A50` = `"apple"`, then I can get the contents of cell `D50`.

I looked at `INDIRECT` and `INDEX`, but I'm not seeing how it can help.

**Answer:**

```
=INDEX('SHEET1'!A:D,MATCH(SHEET2!A2,'SHEET1'!B:B,0),4)
```

I got `INDEX` to work. It took some more reading up on it.

`'SHEET1'!A:D` is the range for `INDEX` to work with.

`MATCH(SHEET2!A2,'SHEET1'!B:B,0)` is pulling the row based upon my `MATCH` criteria.

`4` is the **column** to return the cell contents from using the **row** number from the `MATCH` above.

Hopefully this will help someone else understand how to use `INDEX`.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you don't wish to use VLOOKUP()? It seems that your data is organized in a tabular format.

Comment: I figured out how to get index to work. I'd not run across vlookup before, but it does look like it would have worked.

Comment: You should post your answer as an answer, not an edit to your question. Then you should accept your own answer to flag this question as solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

=INDEX('SHEET1'!A:D,MATCH(SHEET2!A2,'SHEET1'!B:B,0),4)

I got INDEX to work. Took some more reading up on it.

'SHEET1'!A:D is the range for INDEX to work with. MATCH(SHEET2!A2,'SHEET1'!B:B,0) is pulling the row based upon my MATCH criteria. 4 is the COLUMN to return the cell contents from using the ROW number from the MATCH above.

However, the other options given were very helpful as well.

Answer (score 3):

Give VLOOKUP a try.  For example,

```
=VLOOKUP("apple",$A$1:$D$100,4,false)
```

It's a very useful function.

Comment: There are a few reasons why INDEX/MATCH can be better than VLOOKUP. INDEX/MATCH is quicker over very large ranges; doesn't require the lookup field to be before the return field and doesn't have ascending order problems that VLOOKUP sometime encounters.

Answer (score 2):

INDIRECT allows you to refer to any arbitrary cell in the sheet by specifying its location using a dynamic value.  In your case, you'll want to do something like this:

```
=INDIRECT("D"&MATCH(<your match here>))
```

That will return the value of the cell D50 in the example you've given. The Excel documentation says it returns a "reference" to that cell, but in reality it's immediately evaluated to the cell's value.

The main benefit of this approach over `VLOOKUP` is that `INDIRECT` will refer to any arbitrary cell, whereas `VLOOKUP` requires a known data range and a matching value. For example, if your `MATCH` criteria references another sheet from the data you want to pull, your best option is `INDIRECT`.